# If socket timeout set small value, does it have any disadvantage or bug?

Tags: python, sockets, timeout

When I do socket programming with python,
I notice that some operations didn't stop by interrupt. Ex: `accept()` or `recv()`
So I solve this problem using small timeout, that every 1 second, program stop the operation and recall that. For example,

```
socket.settimeout(1)    
while True:
    try:
        socket.recv()
    except timeout:
        # back to socket.recv()
        continue
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Is there some potential problem like losing some messages during timeout exception or heavy load to OS, etc?

And, do you have any better idea to stop socket not using the timeout? Please tell me then I appreciate your answer.

There is one more thing need to consider. I test this program in Windows, and KeyboardInterrupt actually raise after recv() is done even if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. But in MacOS or Linux, KeyboardInterrupt raise just after pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Is there difference between Windows and Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 0):

With sockets, the risk of losing data depends on the socket type.

With `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets, there is no promise that the protocol is *reliable*.  This means that in general you should expect that some messages will be lost no matter how you program `recv()` calls.

With `SOCK_STREAM`, there is a promise that the incoming stream of data will be reliable and in the same order it was sent.

If you call `socket.settimeout(0)` or `socket.setblocking(False)`, then `recv()` checks the socket's receive buffer for incoming data, and if there is none, it [fails with an error that depends on the operating system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-timeouts).  This could be used to *poll* periodically for data while also doing other things.  However, it can also introduce operating system-specific behavior to your program.

Another common technique is to create a thread whose sole purpose is to send and receive a socket that is set to blocking mode [`socket.setblocking(True)`].  In this case the thread can call `recv()` and wait as long as necessary until data actually comes in.  This setup lets you program a protocol as a conversation between `send()` and `recv()` calls.

For applications that handle messages from several sockets at a time, [`select()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) can be used to figure out which sockets in a set have pending data to `recv()`.  One caution is that `select()` can be inefficient in situations that demand high performance.

Comment: A zero timeout value means infinity, not zero. It is not a mechanism for polling the socket.

Comment: @EJP According to documentation for [`socket.settimeout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout), zero puts the socket in non-blocking mode, while None, puts it in blocking mode (infinite timeout).